# Hiding and Binding key in Groth-Sahai NIZK proof system

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In context of [Groth-Sahai NIZK proof system](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155), I have a couple of doubts on Hiding and Binding keys.

[image]

1. In case of hiding keys (highlighted in red), how is it ensured that $\tau(A) \subseteq \langle u_1,...u_m \rangle$?
2. In case of binding keys (highlighted in green), how come $\tau \circ p$ be an identity map on $A$? Shouldn't it be an identity map on $B$?

Comment: I understand, but otherwise I had to Latex so much text. Apart from that, the title and tag fields are searchable.

Comment: I personally find "Groth-Sahai proofs revisited" has a clearer presentation of what's going on, and it fixes a few small mistakes/typos.

Answer (score 2):

I am still not very familiar with these kinds of proofs, but from what I understood:

1) This inclusion is actually a condition which defines in itself what a hiding key is. That is to say that this paragraph does not say that the inclusion is ensured, but that we should make sure that it is, if we want a perfectly hiding key. However, you may find sets of $u_i$'s that verify this property in the three different instantiations. If you use the short version of the paper where they do not appear, look [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155.pdf) instead.

In the second (SXDH) instantiation for instance, to commit in $G_1$, you get $u_1=(\mathcal{P}_1,\alpha\mathcal{P}_1)$ and either $u_2=tu_1$ for a binding key, or $u_2=tu_1-(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{P}_1)$ for a hiding key ($t$ and $\alpha$ are chosen at random). In this last case, $\iota(G_1)\subset \langle u_1,u_2\rangle$ because for $g\in G_1$, you can write $g=\mathcal{P}_1^n$ and then you have $\iota(g)=(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{P}_1^n)=(tu_1-u_2)^n\in\langle u_1,u_2\rangle$. Note that you don't have this with the binding parameters.

2) You are right, they probably meant to write $p\circ\iota$ instead.